# Logitech Mouse cursor shakes, whilst a cheaper brand doesn't?

Tags: mouse, cursor, logitech-mouse

I have a Sweex MI612 (cheap laser mouse) and a Logitech M705 (somewhat less cheaper laser mouse). But when using the Logitech mouse, I get a shaking cursor:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJOeISlWloA

The software is installed and I use both mouses on a normal white table (but result are the same when using a black mousepad.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you have them both plugged in at the same time? If not, are you using the same USB port? Have you installed the Logitech's drivers, or are you relying on Windows default mouse drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Consider where the sensor on the mouse is on both.

On the [Sweex MI612](http://www.sweex.com/en/assortiment/input/laser-mice/MI612/) it is under the thumb while the [Logitech M705](http://www.logitech.com/product/marathon-mouse-m705) has it on the opposite side. Contrast this with the Dell M-UAR DEL7 which like most ambidextrous mice has a centered sensor.

The interaction of this and the dynamics of hand control might be the cause.

Comment: Note that some do not like the M705 due to its off center sensor. Although I don't know if that would extend to the MI612 which is off center in the opposite direction.

Comment: The off center sensor does not bother me on the Sweex. And it doesn't explain the small vibrating. Really weird!

Answer (score 0):

I had this once too, but with another brand laser mouse. In my case it was the old USB harddisk standing on the table; the vibrations were apparently enough to generate minimal mouse movement.

Comment: That's not it. I have no vibrating objects on my table. And it should also effect my Sweex mouse... Tnx thinking with me :-)